# Image loader/writer design (no API, pure C++ on Windows)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, classes, image

I have an image loader, now only for bitmaps. I'm a little confused because I want to split my code to different classes, one for writing a BMP data to a file (*WRITER*), one for loading BMP data from file, or from pre-generated dataset *(1)* and storing it in its private members.*( (1) like a noise function saved to an array)*.

Currently I have the 2 class for this. The header:

```
namespace PND
{

    inline void out(const ::std::string); //standard output log
    inline void err(const ::std::string); //error log

    bool file_exists(::std::string m_filename) //this could be used in both classes
    {
        ::std::ifstream infile(m_filename+".bmp");
        return infile.good();
    }

    class BMP
    {
    public:
        BMP();
        BMP(const BMP&);//copy csrt
        ~BMP();
        BMP& operator= (BMP other); //ass. operator

        bool loadData(::std::string filename);//from file, filename is the file's filename
        bool loadData(::std::string filename,const int width, const int height, const unsigned char* data, const unsigned int length);//from array, filename is user defined
        //they are simple pixel data accessors with out of bounds handling
        unsigned char getData_B(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y);
        unsigned char getData_G(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y);
        unsigned char getData_R(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y);

        unsigned int* getSize() { return m_size; }; //some getter
        ::std::string getName() { return m_filename; };

    private:

        void swap(BMP& other);
        void freeData();
            //the bitmap data:
        BITMAPINFOHEADER m_infoheader;
        BITMAPFILEHEADER m_fileheader;
        ::std::string m_filename;
        unsigned char* m_data;
        unsigned int m_size[2];
        long __m_size; //it is the length of the m_data array (num of pixels * 3)
    };

    class WRITER
    {
    public:
        bool writeData(::std::string filename, const int width, const int height, const unsigned char* data, const unsigned int length);
        bool writeData(::std::string filename, const BMP& bmp);//now this is the problem, more info below the code

    private:
        ::std::ofstream outstream;

        bool openFile(::std::string filename);
        bool writeHeader(const int width,const int height);
        bool writeFile(const unsigned char* data, const unsigned int length);
        bool closeStream();
    };
}
```

I'm in trouble because **I would like to access (read only) the bitmap data (headers, pixel data) from the image - that was saved to a `BMP` object - in the `WRITER` class.** But because they are private members I can not access them in the `writeheader()` and `writefile()` functions. It would be nice to access them without making them public members, and I also try to avoid using inheritance in this case since a **`WRITER` is not really a `BMP`**. Lots of `getters`are also not the best way for accessing arrays I think.

So the `BMP` could only load and save the image data. And with a `WRITER` I can write this data to a .bmp file. I want to make a pretty clean interface with public functions, and do not mix classes if not neccessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only standard ways to access private data from another class are:

1. Getters
2. Friend class

If you want to make a friend class, just do something like this:

```
class Writer ;

class BMP
{
    //...
private:
friend class Writer ;
}
```

Now the `Writer` class can access all of `BMP`'s data fields.

I would personally suggest using getters though. You could have getters for the header information and use `operator []` for accessing any arrays.

```
unsigned char& BMP::operator [] (const size_t i) {
    return m_data [i] ;
}

const unsigned char& BMP::operator [] (const size_t i) const {
    return m_data [i] ;
}
```

Comment: +1 I've never used overloaded []. That's seems much better for accessing arrays thanks! Also, friend functions are the way to go, I think so(never really used them)

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason the `WRITER` class can't be static (i.e. just have all static methods) and then put a `write()` function in the `BMP` class that would just call the static writer methods? You would have to create an overload to take all the private members you would want to pass in (i.e. a write method to take in file name and a `const BITMAPINFOHEADER&` or whatever you might need). Otherwise a friend function (as red_eight mentioned) would be the way to go in your case.

Alternatively if you are trying to separate your classes into a sort of hierarchical reader/writer structure, a possibility would be to have a base `BMP` class that has all the necessary info (like headers, size, filename etc) then having 2 separate classes derived from it, for example using your code:

```
namespace PND
{
    inline void out(const ::std::string); //standard output log
    inline void err(const ::std::string); //error log

    bool file_exists(::std::string m_filename) //this could be used in both classes
    {
        ::std::ifstream infile(m_filename+".bmp");
        return infile.good();
    }

    class BMP
    {
    public:
        BMP();
        BMP(const BMP&);//copy csrt
        virtual ~BMP();
        BMP& operator= (BMP other); //ass. operator

        //they are simple pixel data accessors with out of bounds handling
        unsigned char getData_B(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y);
        unsigned char getData_G(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y);
        unsigned char getData_R(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y);

        unsigned int* getSize() { return m_size; }; //some getter
        ::std::string getName() { return m_filename; };

    protected:
            //the bitmap data:
        BITMAPINFOHEADER m_infoheader;
        BITMAPFILEHEADER m_fileheader;
        ::std::string m_filename;
        unsigned char* m_data;
        unsigned int m_size[2];
        long __m_size; //it is the length of the m_data array (num of pixels * 3)
    private: // NOTE: not sure if these would be private or in BMP_READER
        void swap(BMP& other);
        void freeData();
    };

    class BMP_READER : virtual public BMP
    {
    public:
        bool loadData(::std::string filename);//from file, filename is the file's filename
        bool loadData(::std::string filename, const int width, const int height, const unsigned char* data, const unsigned int length);//from array, filename is user defined
    }

    class BMP_WRITER : virtual public BMP
    {
    public:
        static bool writeData(::std::string filename, const int width, const int height, const unsigned char* data, const unsigned int length);
        bool writeData(); // already have 'm_filename' and access to base BMP

    private:
        ::std::ofstream outstream;

        bool openFile(::std::string filename);
        bool writeHeader(const int width,const int height);
        bool writeFile(const unsigned char* data, const unsigned int length);
        bool closeStream();
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm gonna use friend functions/classes for this. I've not really used them, but I think its the best solution. +1

Comment: Sounds good, sometimes they really are the best answer to a solution; check out [this link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html) for a good example on friend functions if you might need it :)